# How to efficiently compute a high-dimensional volume integral in mathematica?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

The high dimensional integral is to integrate f[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15]*Boole[R], where f is some large (with power of order~10^3) polynomial on the 15 variables:

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_, x10_, x11_, x12_, x13_,
   x14_, x15_] := (1. + 3*p[[1]].xv)^q[[1]]*(1. + 3*p[[2]].xv)^
   q[[2]]*(1. + 3*p[[3]].xv)^q[[3]]*(1. + 3*p[[4]].xv)^
   q[[4]]*(1. + 3*p[[5]].xv)^q[[5]]*(1. + 3*p[[6]].xv)^
   q[[6]]*(1. + 3*p[[7]].xv)^q[[7]]*(1. + 3*p[[8]].xv)^
   q[[8]]*(1. + 3*p[[9]].xv)^q[[9]]*(1. + 3*p[[10]].xv)^
   q[[10]]*(1. + 3*p[[11]].xv)^q[[11]]*(1. + 3*p[[12]].xv)^
   q[[12]]*(1. + 3*p[[13]].xv)^q[[13]]*(1. + 3*p[[14]].xv)^
   q[[14]]*(1. + 3*p[[15]].xv)^q[[15]]
```

with

```
q = {1399, 1434, 1359, 1426, 293, 2497, 2534, 270, 1423, 1363, 1449, 
  1360, 2447, 297, 268, 2527, 1405, 1350, 1371, 1364, 1367, 1345, 
  1456, 1447, 1411, 1367, 1431, 1373, 1322, 1341, 1396, 1385, 276, 
  2461, 2499, 287};

p = {{0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0., 
   0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0., 0.}, {-0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 
   0., -0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 0., 
   0.}, {0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 
   0., -0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0., 0.}, {-0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 
   0., 0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 0., 
   0.}, {0., 0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 
   0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0.}, {0., -0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0., 0., 
   0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 0.}, {0., 
   0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, -0.40825,
    0., 0., 0.40825, 0.}, {0., -0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 0., 
   0., -0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, -0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 
   0.}, {0., 0., 0.40825, 0.8165, 0., 0., 0., -0.2357, 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., 0., -0.40825, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.2357, 0., 
   0., 0.8165, 0., 0., 0., -0.33333}, {0., 0., 0.40825, -0.8165, 0., 
   0., 0., -0.2357, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., 
   0., -0.40825, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.2357, 0., 0., -0.8165, 0., 0., 
   0., -0.33333}, {0.40825, 0., 0., 0., 0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0., 0., 
   0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0.40825, 0., 0.}, {-0.40825, 0., 0., 0., 
   0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 0., 0.40825, -0.40825, 0.,
    0.}, {0.40825, 0., 0., 0., -0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 0., 
   0., -0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 0.40825, 0., 0.}, {-0.40825, 0., 0., 
   0., -0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0., -0.40825, -0.40825,
    0., 0.}, {0., 0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825,
    0., 0., 0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0.}, {0., -0.40825, 0., 0., 
   0.40825, -0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 
   0.}, {0., 0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, -0.40825, 0., 0., 0.40825, 0.,
    0., -0.40825, 0., 0.40825, 0.}, {0., -0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 
   0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 0., 0., -0.40825, 0., -0.40825, 
   0.}, {0., 0., 0.40825, 0., 0.8165, 0., 0., -0.2357, 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., 0., -0.40825, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.2357, 0., 
   0., 0., 0.8165, 0., 0., -0.33333}, {0., 0., 0.40825, 0., -0.8165, 
   0., 0., -0.2357, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., 
   0., -0.40825, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.2357, 0., 0., 0., -0.8165, 0., 
   0., -0.33333}, {0.8165, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.4714, 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0.33333}, {-0.8165, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.4714, 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.4714, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.8165, 0., -0.33333}, {0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., -0.4714, 0., 0., 0., 0., -0.8165, 
   0., -0.33333}, {0., 0.8165, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.4714, 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., -0.8165, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.4714, 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.4714, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.8165, -0.33333}, {0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., -0.4714, 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.8165, -0.33333}, {0., 0., 0.8165, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.4714, 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., 0., -0.8165, 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0.4714, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., -0.94281, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.33333}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1.}};

xv = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, 
  x15};
```

and the Boole function is on some polytope region R defined by a list of linear inequalities:

```
    Boole[p[[1]].xv < v[[1]] \[And] p[[2]].xv < v[[2]] \[And] 
  p[[3]].xv < v[[3]] \[And] p[[4]].xv < v[[4]] \[And] 
  p[[5]].xv < v[[5]] \[And] p[[6]].xv < v[[6]] \[And] 
  p[[7]].xv < v[[7]] \[And] p[[8]].xv < v[[8]] \[And] 
  p[[9]].xv < v[[9]] \[And] p[[10]].xv < v[[10]] \[And] 
  p[[11]].xv < v[[11]] \[And] p[[12]].xv < v[[12]] \[And] 
  p[[13]].xv < v[[13]] \[And] p[[14]].xv < v[[14]] \[And] 
  p[[15]].xv < v[[15]] \[And] p[[16]].xv < v[[16]] \[And] 
  p[[17]].xv < v[[17]] \[And] p[[18]].xv < v[[18]] \[And] 
  p[[19]].xv < v[[19]] \[And] p[[20]].xv < v[[20]] \[And] 
  p[[21]].xv < v[[21]] \[And] p[[22]].xv < v[[22]] \[And] 
  p[[23]].xv < v[[23]] \[And] p[[24]].xv < v[[24]] \[And] 
  p[[25]].xv < v[[25]] \[And] p[[26]].xv < v[[26]] \[And] 
  p[[27]].xv < v[[27]] \[And] p[[28]].xv < v[[28]] \[And] 
  p[[29]].xv < v[[29]] \[And] p[[30]].xv < v[[30]] \[And] 
  p[[31]].xv < v[[31]] \[And] p[[32]].xv < v[[32]] \[And] 
  p[[33]].xv < v[[33]] \[And] p[[34]].xv < v[[34]] \[And] 
  p[[35]].xv < v[[35]] \[And] p[[36]].xv < v[[36]] \[And] 
  p[[1]].xv > v[[37]] \[And] p[[2]].xv > v[[38]] \[And] 
  p[[3]].xv > v[[39]] \[And] p[[4]].xv > v[[40]] \[And] 
  p[[5]].xv > v[[41]] \[And] p[[6]].xv > v[[42]] \[And] 
  p[[7]].xv > v[[43]] \[And] p[[8]].xv > v[[44]] \[And] 
  p[[9]].xv > v[[45]] \[And] p[[10]].xv > v[[46]] \[And] 
  p[[11]].xv > v[[47]] \[And] p[[12]].xv > v[[48]] \[And] 
  p[[13]].xv > v[[49]] \[And] p[[14]].xv > v[[50]] \[And] 
  p[[15]].xv > v[[51]] \[And] p[[16]].xv > v[[52]] \[And] 
  p[[17]].xv > v[[53]] \[And] p[[18]].xv > v[[54]] \[And] 
  p[[19]].xv > v[[55]] \[And] p[[20]].xv > v[[56]] \[And] 
  p[[21]].xv > v[[57]] \[And] p[[22]].xv > v[[58]] \[And] 
  p[[23]].xv > v[[59]] \[And] p[[24]].xv > v[[60]] \[And] 
  p[[25]].xv > v[[61]] \[And] p[[26]].xv > v[[62]] \[And] 
  p[[27]].xv > v[[63]] \[And] p[[28]].xv > v[[64]] \[And] 
  p[[29]].xv > v[[65]] \[And] p[[30]].xv > v[[66]] \[And] 
  p[[31]].xv > v[[67]] \[And] p[[32]].xv > v[[68]] \[And] 
  p[[33]].xv > v[[69]] \[And] p[[34]].xv > v[[70]] \[And] 
  p[[35]].xv > v[[71]] \[And] p[[36]].xv > v[[72]]] 
    with
    v = {0.05007506666666665, 0.059019866666666664, 0.03984266666666669, 
      0.056976266666666664, -0.23965329333333332, 0.32807666666666674, 
      0.3373730666666668, -0.24600645333333335, 0.05620946666666674, 
      0.04086626666666667, 0.0628514666666667, 0.04009826666666664, 
      0.3155078666666667, -0.2385518133333333, -0.24656061333333334, 
      0.33561386666666665, 0.05160866666666671, 0.037538666666666685, 
      0.04291346666666662, 0.041121866666666694, 0.04188986666666672, 
      0.036258266666666726, 0.06463826666666672, 0.062340266666666665, 
      0.053142266666666695, 0.04188986666666672, 0.058253066666666665, 
      0.04342466666666667, 0.030368666666666638, 0.03523466666666667, 
      0.04930706666666662, 0.04649426666666671, -0.24434577333333332, 
      0.31902746666666665, 
      0.32857946666666665, -0.24130737333333332, -0.04091973333333332, \
    -0.03307173333333332, -0.04988133333333333, -0.034865733333333315, \
    -0.2818852533333333, 0.20792906666666666, 
      0.21638666666666664, -0.28656861333333333, -0.03553893333333332, \
    -0.048984933333333314, -0.029705733333333335, -0.04965693333333332, 
      0.19650626666666668, -0.28106745333333333, -0.28697421333333334, 
      0.2147870666666667, -0.03957453333333335, -0.051896133333333316, \
    -0.04719333333333331, -0.0487617333333333, -0.048089733333333294, \
    -0.053014533333333315, -0.028133733333333317, -0.030154533333333327, \
    -0.03822933333333334, -0.048089733333333294, -0.033743733333333324, \
    -0.04674573333333332, -0.05816013333333333, -0.05390973333333334, \
    -0.041592933333333325, -0.04405773333333329, -0.28535025333333336, 
      0.1997042666666667, 0.20838626666666663, -0.28311033333333335}
```

The integration domain is a 15-d cube, which encloses the polytope , specifically,

```
 NIntegrate[
 f[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15]*
  Boole[#as above#], {x1, -0.049062789649998537, 
  0.061991686410356669}, {x2, -0.05719240115732159, 
  0.051609769084544427}, {x3, -0.37010425647667089, \
-0.27192400456561505}, {x4, -0.060251568897083531, 
  0.052612100287291373}, {x5, -0.069031519931115531, 
  0.042880522488188071}, {x6, -0.095675599659265226, 
  0.10758379404380573}, {x7, 0.59447412028983337, 
  0.69595853790472439}, {x8, -0.26262119801536549, \
-0.12415706133192743}, {x9, -0.10319455337371253, 
  0.10006484032935842}, {x10, -0.051036000607194966, 
  0.050448417007696145}, {x11, -0.054552096163575564, 
  0.055433912470977544}, {x12, -0.070640099845201226, 
  0.040669368097377694}, {x13, -0.047255801066747351, 
  0.06429837090113559}, {x14, -0.053942173217622603, 
  0.057174029984250661}, {x15, 0.24130737333333332, 
  0.28311033333333341}, Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^7}]
```

I am using `NIntegrate` with method `MonteCarlo, MaxPoints 10^7`, it still fails to converge. I guess this is normal when dealing with such high dim integration. Shall I try more MaxPoints or is there some way to boost up/simplify the computation, like implementing some Metropolis-Hastings?

Comment: Can't help without an explicit example.  Post your code, defining `f`.

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks and I have edited the post.

Comment: Still not enough: give the full list of inequalities defining the region of integration.  And provide the actual line of code `NIntegrate[...]` that you used.  Don't just describe it.

Comment: @QuantumDot any ideas?

Comment: Copying and pasting the code, running it on my computer doesn't work.   Among other things `xv` isn't defined and `#as above#` is invalid.  It is anyway too complicated; so you'll have to reduce your problem if you expect others to help.